# How can I access an existing javascript object passed back by RequireJS from a PartialView

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, requirejs

Working with ASP.NET MVC, KnockoutJS and I am using Require JS.

I have a view that I am passing back a object that retains 2 Knockout view models.  To keep this simple, the parent view is a list of projects.  You have the ability to Create a new product or edit one on the list by clicking the appropriate button.  Either button will intialize a jQuery dialog which is populated by getting a returned PartialView from my controller.

At the time the partial view is retrieved, I bind a Knockout View model (property on the original returned RequireJS object) to that partial view.  I have no problems creating a new product, taking the KO view model and saving it back to the controller action.

**The Problem**

The problem comes in when attempting to load an existing product into the PartialView. I need to be able to populate the KO viewModel with initial values.  A possible solution would be if I could pass the  MVC View **model** from the controller into my existing RequireJS object I could initialize the KO viewmodel with the existing properties values.  However, I can't figure out how to access the **existing** returned javascript object on the product list view in my partialview view.

The only **wrong** way that I can get the MVC model on the partialview passed in, is if I wire up Require JS on the partial view and pass back a **new** instance of the object and pass in the MVC Model, but that just breaks the current jQuery dialog call backs to the original object.

**Example:**

**Parent Product List View**

```
      ......bunch of html
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>

 @{
   <script type="text/javascript">
      require(['jquery', 'items/adminItemsList', 'jquery-validate-unobtrusive' ],    function ($, viewModel) {
        $(function () {
             viewModel.initialize({
              addUrl: '@Url.Action("Add")',
              listUrl: '@Url.Action("List")',
              editUrl: '@Url.Action("Edit")',
              deleteUrl: '@Url.Action("Delete")'
          });
      });
  });
```

}

**The jQuery Dialog PartialView**

```
      ....bunch of Html
   </div>
  </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    viewModel.Model(@Html.Json(Model))   //I need to be able to do something like this
 </script>
```

The Json method is just a HtmlHelper extension.

How do I setup the returned RequireJS object to be accessible, or what is a better way to design this.

I have and need:

1. I have Product List View
2. A View for a Create/Edit Product
3. The Product list View javascript owns the jQuery Dialog that generates the Create/Edit product view so it needs to not break the callback functions (i.e. onSuccessfulSubmit...)

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered getting the product as JSON from the server, and letting knockout render it with its own template?

Comment: Yes, but since I am using client side validation by utilizing the Data annotations, I am not sure how you could do both if not passing the model into your view (but there easily might be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is splitting out my ViewModels (since really there is two different views) and on the one ViewModel that I need to pass the rendered MVC Model object, I made it an accessible public property off the ViewModel so it can be accessed and serialized by the shared components of the other ViewModel.